# Evaluating $\sum_{k=nq}^{np-1}$...

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

I need to show that those two limits exist and state a formula for them:

a) $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac{n}{k^2}$$

b) $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=nq}^{np-1}\frac{1}{k}$$

with $p,q \in \mathbb{N}, q<p$. I don't know how to approach the problem with the sum starting at $n$.

Comment: Hint for (b) $\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=nq}^{np-1}\frac{1}{k}=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{np-1}\frac{1}{k}-\lim_{n\to\infty} \sum_{k=n}^{nq-1}\frac{1}{k}$ Then it is clearer to see $\lim_{n\to\infty} \log \frac{p}{q}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have that

$$s_n:=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac{n}{k^2} \le \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac{1}{n} = \frac{2n-n}{n} = 1\,,$$

hence the sequence $s_n$ is bounded from above. Now consider

$$s_{n+1}-s_n = \sum_{k=n+1}^{2n+1}\frac{n}{k^2}-\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac{n}{k^2}=\frac{n}{(2n+1)^2}+\frac{n}{(2n)^2}-\frac{1}{n} = -\frac{1+4n}{4n(2n+1)^2} \le0\,,$$
hence it is monotonically decreasing. It follows that the limit exists.

We can provide a lower bound similarly to how we got an upper bound

$$s_n:=\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac{n}{k^2} \ge \sum_{k=n}^{2n-1} \frac{n}{(2n-1)^2} = \frac{n^2}{(2n-1)^2} \ge \frac 14\,,$$

---

Regarding the closed formula, I think it involves the Gamma function (or its derivative, maybe). Definitely not a `nice' one.

EDIT: just realized you asked for the limit, not the closed formula. You could compute it through the Riemannian sums. Relabel your indexes so that

$$\sum_{k=n}^{2n-1}\frac{n}{k^2} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{n^2}{(k+n)^2} = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(\frac{k+n}{n}\right)^2}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\frac{1}{\left(1 + \frac{k}{n}\right)^2} = \int_0^1 \frac{dx}{(1+x)^2} = \frac 12$$

---

You could proceed the same for the other series.

Comment: Thanks! What's the difference of the actual limit and a closed formula in this case?

Comment: A closed formula is a formula depending on $n$ which tells you the value of $s_n$ without the need of a summation. If you have it, then to get $\lim_n s_n$ you just compute the limit on the closed formula.

Comment: Closed formula looks to be $n(\psi'(n)-\psi'(2n))$, where $\psi$ is the digamma function, but I'll let those more expert in number theory to do the thing.

Comment: Thanks! Two small question regarding the first part. Isn't it $\frac{2n-1-n}{n}$ (which would be then $<1$) in the first line and you take $s_{n-1}-s_n$ but I think you want to take $s_{n+1}-s_n$?

Comment: It's (upper bound-lower bound+1) because you are counting both the first index and last index. So you get $2n-1-n+1=n$. On the other hand, you are right. I'll correct the typo, I meant $s_{n+1}$.